# I need to read filenames from one date to another on user input in bash

Tags: linux, bash, date

I need your help. I have a script that needs to read files named from one date to another on user input dates.

In the directory are a lot of files that have the date in the name, ej:

```
xxxx20200930.txt_001
xxxx20200930.txt_002
xxxx20201001.txt_001
xxxx20201001.txt_002
xxxx20201002.txt_001
xxxx20201002.txt_002
```

For example:

```
Indicate star date: 20200930
Indicate finish date: 20200202
```

I need to `cat` between all the files and then a `grep` (I have all this resolved)

I have tried with the date function but I always have problems:

date: fecha invÃ¡lida Â«dateinput2Â»
date: fecha invÃ¡lida Â«dateinputÂ»

```
startdate='dateinput'
enddate='dateinput2'


while [ ! "$(date -d ${dateinput})" ]; do
     read -p "Indicate a date please: " dateinput
done

While [ ! "$(date -d ${dateinput2})" ]; do
     read -p "Indicate a second date please: " dateinput2
done

enddate=$( date -d "$enddate" +%Y%m%d )   # rewrite in YYYYMMDD format
                                                  #  and take last iteration into account
thedate=$( date -d "$startdate" +%Y%m%d )
while [ "$thedate" != "$enddate" ]; do
    printf 'The date is "%s"\n' "$thedate"
    thedate=$( date -d "$thedate + 1 days" +%Y%m%d ) # increment by one day
done
```

That is some code that I found in here but I can't make it work

Can anybody help me.

Thanks

Comment: Given the `xxxx` parts of the filenames, will they list in correct order with `printf "%s\n" *.txt*` ?

Comment: The xxxx parts is the same of all, it doesn't change at all. I will only use cat of that range of dates. I don't know if that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Working with what I have, given

```
$: printf "%s\n" *.txt*
xxxx20200930.txt_001
xxxx20200930.txt_002
xxxx20201001.txt_001
xxxx20201001.txt_002
xxxx20201002.txt_001
xxxx20201002.txt_002
xxxx20201003.txt_001
xxxx20201003.txt_002
xxxx20201004.txt_001
xxxx20201004.txt_002
```

I used this:

```
start=20201001
end=20201003
started=0
ending=0
for f in *.txt*
do case "$f" in
   *"$start".txt*) started=1; echo "$f"; continue ;;
     *"$end".txt*) ending=1;  echo "$f"; continue ;;
   *) (( started )) ||                   continue;
      (( ending  )) &&                   continue;
      echo "$f"                                   ;;
   esac
done
```

Outputs -

```
xxxx20201001.txt_001
xxxx20201001.txt_002
xxxx20201002.txt_001
xxxx20201002.txt_002
xxxx20201003.txt_001
xxxx20201003.txt_002
```

Relies heavily on short-circuit logic.
Filenames may break it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Paul, i added an if for the case if start and end are equal:

```
read -p "Ingrese Fecha comienzo" start
read -p "Ingrese Fecha final" end
read -p param1
read -p param2
read -p param3
start=$start
end=$end
started=0
ending=0
if [[ "$start" == "$end" ]];
then
 (cat *"$start".txt*)
else

for f in *.txt*
do case "$f" in
   *"$start".txt*) started=1; echo "$f"; continue ;;
     *"$end".txt*) ending=1;  echo "$f"; continue ;;
   *) (( started )) ||                   continue;
      (( ending  )) &&                   continue;
      echo "$f"                                   ;;
   esac
done

fi
```

The problem is that i need to do this for all the files but i tried and didn´t work only for the first, i tried to replaze it for the echo "$f"

```
cantlineas=`cat $f | grep "$param1" | grep "$param2" | grep "$param3" |  wc -l`
```

The other param are prompt input user.

Comment: are the params always in the same order on the lines in the file? Or could their order be unpredictable? If order is known, then maybe `cantlineas=$(grep -c "$param1.*$param2.*$param3" "$f")`